# How would I get these two pieces of code to run together?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am looking for a way to hide / show a tkinter window using the key p.

```
import keyboard
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1000x1000")
greeting = tk.Label(text="Hello, Tkinter.")
greeting.pack(pady=10)
root.mainloop()
while not keyboard.is_pressed('p'):
    root.withdraw()
while not keyboard.is_pressed('p'):    
    root.deiconify()
```

- My problem is that I can't get the code to run infinitely without messing up the `root.mainloop()`.
- I seriously have no idea what to do.
- The code I'm talking about is after the mainloop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to bind the key to do something. Heres an example:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

def key_presses(e):
    print('q was pressed')

root.bind('q', key_pressed)
```

The code above prints `'q was pressed'`, well every time it's pressed.

Comment: Yes but once the window loses focus, it wont receive any more key bindings.

Comment: unfortunately thats how tkinter works :(